# Bootstrap accordion: меню аккордеона уходит за пределы экрана

Tags: bootstrap, javascript, css

Есть такой код: 
http://jsbin.com/ikunuv/2/edit

По задумке левое меню должно прокручиваться при очень "длинном" содержимом меню аккордеона.
Сейчас "по умолчанию" меню уходит за пределы экрана. Я хотел бы это исправить, но не знаю как.

Необходимо чтобы меню фиксировалось внизу экрана (не уходило за пределы) и при этом появлялась полоса прокрутки внутри блока аккордеона.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте максимальную высоту например 
    .scroll-content {
          overflow-y:scroll;max-height:200px;
    }

Comment: Тут возникает проблема в том, что заранее высота неизвестна. Значение в процентах также не получится задать (разных мониторах будет выглядеть по разному).